# word for moving an element into another array at a corresponding index?

Tags: arrays, terminology

Something similar to the word *move* would do the trick.

Imagine that I was instead talking about people in a line, rather than an element in an array

"I **moved** Person A out of Line 1 to Line 2"

Now, this is nearly what I am looking for, except there is one other thing I need the verb to do, which is to emphasize an ORDER or the fact that it was moved to a corresponding place within the line/array.

To say this using the word "move" I would have to say:

"I **moved** Person A out of Line 1 ***at Line Position Alpha*** to Line 2 ***at that same position (Line Position Alpha)***"

that is to say, I recorded Person A's place in line, took him out of Line 1, and had him cut in line at the position I recorded, so he doesn't "loose his place in line."

The purpose of this word is to name a small section (and I mean small in comparison to the whole; the section itself is quite a large script) in my program. The program (as you could figure out) has these things similar to lines (called arrays), things similar to people in a line (called elements), and things similar to line positions (array indeces). I do not mean to insult your intelligence; I just want to be sure I get the point across.

So, conclusively, what is the technical-term/word I am looking for?

**EDITOR's NOTE:** To be fully honest, I have never seen a question like this before on stackoverflow, so I have no idea if it is even appropriate to ask on this site

Comment: I would treat it as two operations and use "extract (from)" and "insert (at)".

Comment: @PaulR I thought of that except both of them do me a disfavor, and that is I need both "from" and "at" to be emphasized single-wordedly, because it will be used in a name, and lengthy names are well, just not efficient.